# How to display javascript variables in html

Tags: javascript, printing, innerhtml

I have the the following javascript variables.

```
 goalDiv ="<div class=goal-parent id=goal-parent"+Id+">"+
    "<div class=goal>"+
    "<div class=top-layer>"+
    "<div class=component>"+

    "<select class=component-select>"+
    "<option id=one><span id='source_name'></span></option>"+
    "</select>"+

    "</div>"+
"</div>"+
"</div>"+
"</div>";

Id = "some div value";
```

I am trying to show values inside these divs. I first show this goalDiv into a div and then try to update the values inside it, like following.

```
document.getElementById(Id).innerHTML = goalDiv;
document.getElementById('source_name').innerHTML = "some value";
```

The first innerHTML works but the second doesn't. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: can you show a js fiddle example

Comment: `<option>` doesn't accept HTML, it accepts `.text = ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have `span` inside `option`.
If you want to change the dropdown options simply use:

```
document.getElementById('one').innerHTML = "some value";
```

Comment: giving <option> an id and using .innerHTML still doesn't work. I also tried .text but that doesn't work either.

Comment: There must be something else i am doing wrong then. Thank you so much for you help :)

Comment: It worked. I don't know what i was doing wrong. But what if i want to show multiple values in the dropdown. Will i have to give each option an id? and how would i predefine that?

Comment: You can use the `options` array of the select. See here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_select_options.asp